# Run jest sequentially and concurrently

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

Is it possible to run all tests concurrently (as it is by default), except for some ones that I want to execute sequentially? If so, how?

I need this because I have some tests that inserts the same data on the database, but the table they are being inserted to have some "unique" constraints. Because of that, some tests fail because another one have already inserted that value.

The tests that cause the problem are in different files.

Also, if you have other alternatives to solve this issue, they are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Tests within the same file are run sequentially.

I assume you need to utilize *beforeAll* / *afterAll* (*beforeEach* / *afterEach*) hooks in order to initialize and dispose db properly.

If you still have an issue, e.g. across different test suites, consider using a separate DB for each test suite (through *setupFiles*)

Comment: The tests that cause the problem are in different files. I've updated the question. 

I'll study more about using different DBs